# reversing order of bytes in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

This has been surprisingly difficult. I am extracting bits to collect information from an array of unsigned chars. There is one part I am stuck on. The array has these four bytes: 0x79,0xE8,0x39,0x1A contained in it and I need to reverse them to get 0x1A, 0x39, 0xE8, 0x79. My reverse_order function instead gives me 0x59,0x4,0x89,0x10 (which are other bytes in array):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LATITUDE_OFFSET 4
#define LONGITUDE_OFFSET 5

void reverse_order(unsigned char *start, unsigned char *end)
{
    int i = 4;
    do {
        *start = *end;
        ++start;
        --end;
        --i;
    } while(i > 0);
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
        printf("the value: 0x%x\n", start[j]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char msg[] = {
        0x28,0x83,0x63,0x20,0x79,
        0xE8,0x39,0x1A,0x59,0x04,
        0x89,0x10,0x8D,0x2E,0xF1,
        0x11,0x6E,0x00,0x10,0x8D,
        0x51,0x57,0x29,0x0D
    };  
    unsigned long long int time_secs;
    unsigned char *start, *end;

    int i, j;

    //remove garbage
    time_secs = 0;
    i = 0;      

    while(msg[i] == 0x28)
    {
        ++i;
    }

    unsigned char resp = ((msg[i] & 0xF) * 16) + 7;
    unsigned char resp2 = (msg[i] & 0xF);
    ++i;

    int unit_id_length = ((msg[i++] & 0xC0) >> 6)+1;

    int is_latitude_south = (msg[i] & 0x10) >> LATITUDE_OFFSET;
    int is_longitude_west = (msg[i] & 0x20) >> LONGITUDE_OFFSET;

    ++i;
    start = &msg[i];
    i+=3;
    end = &msg[i];      
    reverse_order(start, end);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of `reverse_order()` based on the original version:

```
void reverse_order(unsigned char *start, unsigned char *end)
{
    int i = 2;
    int t;
    do {
        t = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = t;
        ++start;
        --end;
        --i;
    } while(i > 0);
    int j;
    start -= 2;
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
        printf("the value: 0x%x\n", start[j]);
    }
}
```

---

Here is a revised version:

```
void
reverse(unsigned char *start, unsigned char *end)
{
    unsigned char t;

    while (start < end) {
        t = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = t;

        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I marked your answer correct, but just out of curiosity, do you think something like this is better achieved using memcpy?

Comment: @JohnMerlino I do not think `memcpy()` is helpful at here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following problems with your code:

1. You need to swap the values of `*start` and `*end`.
2. You need to decrement `i` by `2` in the loop. Otherwise, you will re-swap the values.
3. By the time you are printing the values, you have already incremented `start` so that it does not point to where it was when the function was called.

Here's what I came up with:

```
void reverse_order(unsigned char *start, unsigned char *end)
{
    int i = 4;
    unsigned char cp;
    unsigned char* iter = start;
    int j;

    do {
        /* Swap the contents of *iter and *end */
        cp = *iter;
        *iter = *end;
        *end = cp;
        ++iter;
        --end;
        i -= 2;
    } while(i > 0);
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
        printf("the value: 0x%x\n", start[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine your byte ordering with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    union {
        short s;
        char c[sizeof(short)];
    }un;
    un.s = 0x0102;

    if (sizeof(short) == 2) {
        if (un.c[0] == 1 && un.c[1] == 2)
            printf("big-endian\n");
        else if (un.c[0] == 2 && un.c[1] == 1)
            printf("little-endian\n");
        else
            printf("unknown\n");
   } else{
        printf("sizeof(short) = %d\n", sizeof(short));
   }
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What I want to do is reverse the specified four bytes, not determine whether little endian or big endian is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Your reverse code doesn't work correctly.

Use a temporary variable:

```
unsigned char t = *start ;
*start = *end;
*end = t ;
```

You also only do half iterations, so in your case `i` in the function reverse_order() would be 2

The argument end of the function is unnecessary since you have a hardcoded length of 4. Rather calculate end in the function

```
unsigned char* end = star + 3 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this nice XOR trick that allows exchanging two variables without using a temporary:

```
void reverse_order(unsigned char *start, unsigned char *end)
{
    while (end > start) {
        *start ^= *end;
        *end ^= *start;
        *start ^= *end;
        ++start;
        --end;
    };
}
```

Its probably not faster and most likely needs some comments but its always good to show how well you have learned your bitwise logic ;)